# Flutter Bloc Exception issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

After using Bloc in my flutter application, I went into these two issues.
First, when I click the Login button, nothing happens and I got this error in the console.(see first image)
Second, when I click the Register button I got another error in the console.(see image 2)

[Login Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaPDf.png)
[Register error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O63re.png)

You can use the link to my repo to check the project on GitHub: git@github.com:GANONTHA/mynotebook.git

This is the code in the AuthBloc file

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  AuthBloc(AuthProvider provider) : super(const AuthStateUninitialized()) {
    //send email verifiction
    on<AuthEventSendEmailVerification>((event, emit) async {
      await provider.sendEmailVerification();
      emit(state);
    });
    //Register
    on<AuthEventRegister>((event, emit) async {
      final email = event.email;
      final password = event.password;
      try {
        await provider.createUser(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
        await provider.sendEmailVerification();
        emit(const AuthStateNeedsVerification());
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        emit(AuthStateRegistering(e));
      }
    });
    //initialize
    on<AuthEventInitialize>((event, emit) async {
      await provider.initialize();
      final user = provider.currentUser;
      if (user == null) {
        emit(
          const AuthStateLoggedOut(
            exception: null,
            isLoading: false,
          ),
        );
      } else if (!user.isEmailVerified) {
        emit(const AuthStateNeedsVerification());
      } else {
        emits(AuthStateLoggedIn(user));
      }
    });
    //login
    on<AuthEventLogIn>((event, emit) async {
      emit(const AuthStateLoggedOut(
        exception: null,
        isLoading: true,
      ));
      final email = event.email;
      final password = event.password;
      try {
        final user = await provider.logIn(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
        if (!user.isEmailVerified) {
          emit(
            const AuthStateLoggedOut(
              exception: null,
              isLoading: false,
            ),
          );
          emit(const AuthStateNeedsVerification());
        } else {
          emit(
            const AuthStateLoggedOut(
              exception: null,
              isLoading: false,
            ),
          );
          emit(AuthStateLoggedIn(user));
        }

        emit(AuthStateLoggedIn(user));
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        emit(AuthStateLoggedOut(
          exception: e,
          isLoading: false,
        ));
      }
    });
    //log out
    on<AuthEventLogOut>((event, emit) async {
      try {
        await provider.logOut();
        emit(const AuthStateLoggedOut(
          exception: null,
          isLoading: false,
        ));
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        emit(AuthStateLoggedOut(
          exception: e,
          isLoading: false,
        ));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And this is the code in the Auth_event file

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show immutable;

//defining classes with their constructor
@immutable
abstract class AuthEvent {
  const AuthEvent();
}

class AuthEventInitialize extends AuthEvent {
  const AuthEventInitialize();
}

class AuthEventSendEmailVerification extends AuthEvent {
  const AuthEventSendEmailVerification();
}

class AuthEventLogIn extends AuthEvent {
  final String email;
  final String password;
  const AuthEventLogIn(this.email, this.password);
}

class AuthEventRegister extends AuthEvent {
  final String email;
  final String password;
  const AuthEventRegister(this.email, this.password);
}

class AuthEventShouldRegister extends AuthEvent {
  const AuthEventShouldRegister();
}

class AuthEventLogOut extends AuthEvent {
  const AuthEventLogOut();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first error I would recommend to make the parameter mandatory like this.

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
 final AuthProvider authProvider;

 AuthBloc({required this.authProvider}) : super(const AuthStateUninitialized()) 
 {
  ...
 }
```

Check if you are injecting the provider properly. Sometimes you forgot to set up the injection and the compiler does not know how to handle this.

For the "register error" you forgot to define the AuthEventShouldRegister event on your BLOC in order to handle it properly when an event of this type is added.